# Rosserial and Arduino DUE

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried to compile a .ino for my Arduino DUE with rosserial package and Arduino IDE-1.5.2, but this warning happens :

```
ArduinoHardware.h:68: warning: undefined reference to `HardwareSerial::begin(unsigned long)'
```

And that is surely why I can't communicate with serial port when I use ROS :

```
Lost sync with device
```

However, the code compiles and works with an Arduino MEGA.

Does anyone had this problem before ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58053/rosserial-and-arduino-due/) by [Yeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/4419/yeti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [0pc0](https://answers.ros.org/users/1936/0pc0/) on 2013-06-28**:
Have you found a resolution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is necessary to use UARTClass or USARTClass (which are subclasses of HardwareSerial). See http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=142753.0. I haven't gotten Rosserial communicating yet, but my progress notes are here: http://wiki.jigren.org/index.php?title=Rosserial_On_Arduino_Due

---

Originally posted by [cha](https://answers.ros.org/users/5989/cha/) with karma: 41 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cha](https://answers.ros.org/users/5989/cha/) on 2013-08-18**:
Got it working. See also https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/pull/58 .